# Central heating/cooling system heating unevenly

Tags: heating

I have just had a new 3.5 ton central air and heating unit installed. The main vent is located in the hallway right next to the middle bedroom.

When I turn the unit on to heat my home the heat in all of the rooms are distributed evenly but the heat in the middle bedroom distribution is much hotter than in the other rooms in my home. How can I makes the adjustments so that it's not so hot in that middle bedroom.

Comment: The main inlet (air return to the furnace), or main outlet (conditioned air from the furnace)? (I'm assuming the former, and there are a number of smaller outlet vents scattered through the house.)

Answer (score 1):

The "Registers" on the blowy holes are adjustable down to fully closed. The Grills on the sucky holes are not adjustable. You should find that the middle room's Register can be almost completely closed in order to maintain an even temperature equal to the other rooms.

Unfortunately, this adjustment or setting only applies to heating as you discovered upon switching from cooling. You'd need to either manually set the middle room's Register each heating &/or heating season or have a programmable & motorized External Register or Internal Damper installed to do it for you.